# Setting up Layout in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Hello I am using Gatsby to build my application using a stock market API and I am new to Gatsby. I am trying to wrap each of my pages around `<Layout> </Layout>` because inside my layout.js there is a header and footer, then on all of my pages, there will be the same heading and footer without repeating code. The error I am getting is `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

That error is from the following code in `layout.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

import Header from "./header"
import Footer from "./footer"
import "./layout.css"


const Layout = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
        {props.children}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}


export default Layout
```

I have tried switching the `layout.js` to class based component and got the same error:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

import Header from "./header"
import Footer from "./footer"
import "./layout.css"


export class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
          {this.props.children}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is my  `index.js` file:

```
import React from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import '../CSS/index.scss'
import Layout from "../components/layout"


export default class index extends React.Component {
    state = {
        companyName: "",
        previousClose: "",

    }

    clickHandler = (event) => {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            const query = event.target.value;
            const API_KEY = '*****************';
        axios.get(`https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${query}/quote?token=${API_KEY}`)
            .then(res => {
                const companyName = res.data['companyName'];
                this.setState({ companyName })

                const previousClose = res.data['previousClose'];
                this.setState({ previousClose })
            })
        }
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <div class = "main-div">
                    <input type="search" class="main-search" onKeyDown={event => this.clickHandler(event)}/>
                    <h3>{this.state.companyName}</h3>
                    <p>{this.state.previousClose}</p>
                </div>
            </Layout>
        )
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-default",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simple starter to get up and developing quickly with Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Kyle Mathews <mathews.kyle@gmail.com>",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "gatsby": "^2.22.15",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.4.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.4.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.2.7",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.3.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.9",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.8",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.5.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.0.5"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use `import {Layout} from "../components/layout"` because your export is not "default". Did you try this?

Comment: I am getting this error now not sure if it is relate: ``` Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Web Development\React Projects\gatsby-stockmarketAPI\node_modules\node-sass\lib' ```

Comment: it says this in the next line ```If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'fs' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct. ``` is there an npm command I can use to install fs maybe?

Comment: ```npm install fs``` did not change anything still the same error.

Comment: Maybe `npm install` will help

Comment: Can you show your package.json?

Comment: Tried ```npm install``` same error. I shared my package.json in my updated code though

Comment: `npm install node-sass`?

Comment: If your API_KEY is real it is better to hide it from question for security reasons.

Comment: Did not work, the actual error number for this is ``` ERROR #98124  WEBPACK``` from googling it, it looks like something messed up in my files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, Gatsby is not compatible with code that depends on `fs`. Rather Gatsby loads all its data during the build process which is then available at runtime via the GraphQL API.

Comment: What do I do to fix this?

Comment: You can read this [issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/564). There is a fix there but it doesn't work for everyone.

Comment: okay thanks must have installed something wrong, Ill have to just create a new gatsby project

Comment: What stock-market api are you using? Gatsby is very 'plugin-centric' so if there is not already a Gatsby plugin for the code you are trying to use with Gatbsy then you may have to write your own.

Comment: Do not know a whole lot about gatsby tbh, I figured out how to use some of the features and figured I would build a project, will have to look into plugins.